# How to manage two git repos as a single repo, yet stay separate?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, repository

I've seen other questions about this, but can't relate them to being the same.

I have a theme I've cloned from `GitHub`, which becomes the `master` branch.

Then I create a new local branch for my web page content within the originally cloned theme and I want to check my page content into my own repository on GitLab so I add remote repos for the content branch. At this point, the master remote is different from the branch remote.

By not merging my content branch into the master, I can always pull from the remote of the master which updates the web theme, and then switch to the content branch and develop/update my content. So they're kind of separate w/ no intent on merging.

The problem then becomes ... in order to run `GitLab Pages`, the site is generated from the master branch. But I can't merge my content branch into the master branch 1) because the master has remote repos pointed elsewhere (original GitHub theme repo), and 2) if I could pull updates from the master, it would overwrite changes in my content branch.

So my requirements are that:

```
1) I can keep the remote theme seperate from my own content.
2) Add my own content to the theme and develop.
2) Join the theme and the content into a repo on GitLab for Pages to work.
3) Later update just the theme, and then overlay my content on the new theme and continue to develop.
```

Anyone have thoughts how to organize this properly?

Comment: Nothing prevents you from having your GitLab master branch being different from your GutHub master branch. I think you just need to merge `GitHub/master` into `GitLab/develop`, as you do to work on the pages, and then merge `GitLab/develop` into `GitLab/master` for publication to GitLab Pages.

Comment: Make a local branch in your sandbox called `publish` that has `GitLab/master` as its upstream, and then merging into `publish` and pushing it should update your GitLab Pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your situation correctly, publishing to your GitLab Pages requires pushing the publication-ready version onto your GitLab repo as `master`.

In order to accomplish this, all you need to remember is that the `master` branches on your GitHub and GitLab repos don't need to be related, even if you have a sandbox that points to both remotes, as you describe.

To create a local branch, let's call it `publish`, that points to your GitLab's `master` branch and distinguish it from your template's master branch on GitHub, you can do this:

```sh
git checkout develop
git checkout -b publish
git branch -u gitlab/master
```

Now, when you're on local branch `publish` and have merged everything into it in the state your want it published, run `git push` and it will update `gitlab/master` with your local `publish` branch.

**Assumptions:**

- You called your second remote, on GitLab, `gitlab`, e.g., by running:

  `git remote add gitlab URL_TO_YOUR_GITLAB_REPO`
- There's already a `master` branch on the `gitlab` remote.
- You've previously fetched from `gitlab`, e.g., by running `git fetch gitlab`, so that your sandbox has a reference to `gitlab/master`.

Comment: Let me see if I understand this correctly. In this scenario, I create an empty repo, then create three branches (call them theme, develop, and publish). Then go into publish and 1) merge theme, then 2) merge content, and then push to GitLab master?

Comment: Yeah, that sounds right.

Comment: `theme` would presumably track the GitHub master branch. I'm not sure where you want your `content` branch to live, but I was calling it `develop` in my answer. It could even be in a third repo, if you want theme, contents and publication repos to all be separate. And `publish` in my answer is as you say, where everything gets merged for publication.

Comment: Question: do you ever merge `theme` into `content`, or are the two completely independent, and only assembled together into `publish`? Either way, my answer should still work.

Comment: I only ever merge (overlay) the content (develop) onto the theme. The theme is in a remote repo on GitHub. I grab that, then make my changes, yet those changes (develop) are independent (because they require a different setup when run locally than from how they run in GitLab Pages). Otherwise, a theme update would overwrite my development. I'm working through it.

Comment: Each time I try `git branch -u gitlab/master`, I get `error: the requested upstream branch 'gitlab/master' does not exist`, I did add the remote pointing to `gitlab`. I even recreated the repo from new in GitLab. I was in the `publish` branch when I ran that command.

Comment: Right, I was expecting your GitLab repo to already exist with a master branch on it. Let me look up how to do this when it's not already the case.

Comment: I think the simplest solution is to go to GitLab and create that repo, and create an initial commit there. Afterwards, run `git fetch gitlab` in your sandbox, and then the `git branch -u gitlab/master` command should work.

Comment: When I cloned the initial repo, I cloned from GitHub which had remotes to https://github.com/... Then I checkout out a `develop` branch (added my changes), then from `develop` I checked out a `publish` branch, then tried `git branch -u gitlab/master`, and got the error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238073/discussion-between-joanis-and-ender).